# How to store a tensor flow model in Google Colab?

Tags: python, tensorflow, serialization, pickle

I trained a model in Tensorflow and it took me 4 hours. It is a model = Sequential(). Now, I'd like to store it, and recall it in other notebooks and make comparison. I tried to use pickle however, when I try to dump it onto the google drive. It gives me the following error. What am I doing wrong please?

> ----> 1 pickle.dump(model,fileObject)
>         2 
>         3 # here we close the fileObject
>         4 fileObject.close()
>         5 # we open the file for reading
>
> TypeError: can't pickle _thread._local objects

Answer (score 1):

you can save your model by calling `model.save("my_model.h5")` to save your model and upload it colab for inference.

keras model is not supported by pickle. It uses an HDF5 binary data format to save the model as binary data in a hard disk.

you can also upload your model to google drive and access it in colab by mounting your google drive to your current colab notebook.

like this -

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/gdrive')

with open('/gdrive/My Drive/foo.txt', 'w') as f:
  f.write('Hello Google Drive!')
```

in next cell type this to view your saved file

```
!cat '/gdrive/My Drive/foo.txt'
```

please visit colab code snippets(at left sidebar) section for more sample codes to access google drive form colab.